# Laravel and Angular(JS), where to start with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm a software engineer and want to learn developing web applications with PHP and JavaScript. I'm familliar with C#, object oriented programming and working with frameworks.

So i decided to learn directly creating an web application based on a framework (Laravel, as we work with this framework on my work also). I start understanding how the framework works and as programming is not new for me i also understand the basics of PHP.

For the front-end i want to use Angular JS as i heard a lot of positive things about it. During my research on Google about Angular and Angular in combination with Laravel i read that we already have Angular V2 and V4.

I have a few questions about this:

1. What is the best version to start with? This because i heared the
   good things about V1 (and the combi with Laravel), but V2 and V4 has
   a complete other concept? I'm a bit confused if it has the same
   purpose and if it is still a good approach to combine the newer
   versions with Laravel?
2. I can find how to combine Laravel with AngularJS(1) and how to structure the project, but cant find a good tutorial or explaination how to combine/structure Laravel with
   Angular 2 or 4. This also confuses me.... Are the newer versions not
   a good combination with Laravel anymore?, Angular just uses Json
   API's so why not? or are i'm wrong.
3. What i found about Laravel and the newer Angular versions is that it is a no-go to use both in 1 project. The advice is to use 2
   different projects? I do not understand why as i can still make them
   independed from eachtoher in 1 project by a nice folder structure.
   So if this is true, what is the reason behind?
4. If it is no problem to combine both in 1 project, i prefer to do this. But what is the best practice to add Angular into the Laravel project? especially for the folder structure? Is there a tutorial which describes how to use these 2 frameworks in 1 project?

I hope that someone can give me a "kickstart" how to start with increasing my skills.

Comment: this is an opinion question... If you don't already know PHP, maybe you should learn a different language... if you were to write a front-end with Ember - and a backend with Node... then you would be using JavaScript on both, for example... I'd bet people will close this question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I hope not this question will be closed, and i know it is kindly a opinion question. But i just hope to find some advice where to start and i thought this could be the right place. I also hope that this question helps other people who are looking for a good kickstart for php/javascript development.(where my question goes about)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Vue.js instead if you are familiar with new Laravel 5.x. It is supported by default and plays together pretty good.

https://learninglaravel.net/topics/vuejs

In my previous projects I used Laravel 3/4 + Backbone.js. Backbone, to me, is much better then diving into a full framework that your entire structure ( html + js ) depends on multiple custom tags etc. Backbone gives you a better approach on that case that you can use it partially in some modules etc or you can build your entire layout with it.

Comment: https://medium.com/@chriscordle/why-angular-2-4-is-too-little-too-late-ea86d7fa0bae

Comment: I never heard about Vue(2), i just read something about it and looks very interesting and i wil defenitely give it a try. Doest it also support 2 way databinding and is it fast as Angular (as it seems to be very fast what i have seen)?

Comment: I believe so. I only used it once in a small part of an application and looked very promising. It is not very complicated like angular or ember yet seems powerful

Comment: yeah, Vuejs plays really well with Laravel, and still gives you most of the good stuff from angular